# Filter stock in intraday based on positive day close value

Tags: pine-script

I want to set alert for only those stocks where the change is positive and when a cross of a moving average takes place. So i wrote the below code. Please see it and please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
//@version=4

study(title="test-a", shorttitle="t-a", overlay=true)

// I want to set alert for only those stocks where the change is positive 
//and when a cross of a moving average takes place.
// so i wrote the below code


// Get Daily close to calculate change % to identify +ve stocks only 
// for taking long position
dayclose = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",close)
isPositiv = (dayclose - dayclose[1])/dayclose[1]*100 > 1


// keep the chart on intraday time frame say, 15min.

em1 = ema(close,3)
em2 = ema(close,9)
emp1 = plot(em1,color=color.red) 
emp2 = plot(em2)

// highlight the candle for the stocks where day change isPositiv 
//and em1 cross over em2 in the intraday time frame)

// test 1
yesHighlight  = crossover(em1,em2) and isPositiv
bgcolor(yesHighlight ? #cc0000 : na)
alertcondition(yesHighlight,title="Buy EMCross",message="buy emcross")

// In above test no candle is getting highlighted. Though the stock is a positive stock.
// However,if I remove the isPositiv condition, candles are getting highlighted

// What I am expecting is that every such candle in the intraday timeframe 
// where the above cross takes place to be highlighted as the 
// stock remains positive throughout the day.
// But that is not happening. So what is wrong with the code above. Is the change formula wrong?
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
dailyChangeIsPos = roc(close, 1) * 100 > 1
isPositiv = security(syminfo.tickerid,"D",dailyChangeIsPos)
```

All your daily calculations need to be done in `security()`'s daily context.

And `roc()` gives you the % change over a given period.

[image]